# Why does \nobreak in tabular breaks the line?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rp{1cm}}%
  1&\nobreak\hfill\rlap{9}\\
  1&a\nobreak\hfill\rlap{9}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which compiles to this:

[image]

Why does this happen if I explicitly add the `\nobreak`?

My first idea was that maybe, somehow, when starting the table cell TeX was in vertical mode then the `\nobreak` had a different effect, but then I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rp{1cm}}%
  1&\ifvmode v\else h\fi\nobreak\hfill\rlap{9}\\
  1&a\nobreak\hfill\rlap{9}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which compiles to:

[image]

Which shows that TeX *is* horizontal mode. Or is horizontal mode triggered by typesetting the `h` (I know it doesn't make sense). Or maybe TeX is in Schrödinger mode :)

Comment: Funny enough, if I move the if-else to *after* the `\nobreak`, the first line prints 'v', the 2nd, 'h',

Comment: @remco Interesting :) Looks like `\nobreak` is somehow triggering vertical mode which, again, doesn't make any sense (for me at least).

Comment: Any `\penalty` at the same position has the same effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the start of a `p` column tex is in vertical mode so `\nobreak` (which is really plain tex not to be used in latex) will add a penalty to the vertical list preventing a break (if you had used `\nolinebreak` the behaviour would be different)

The `\ifvmode` test at the start of a cell does not do what you expect as you would get the same value for `l` or `p` cells or array math cells as the expansion happens while tex is looking for `\omit` (`\multicolumn`) so it gives the same answer for all cells *before* tex decide to insert the implict parbox for `p` column. (to see this compare `&\ifvmode` with `&\relax\ifvmode` where the `relax` triggers the insertion of the column template and so then you can distinguish an h mode `c` column from a vmode `p` column.

The vertical offset that you see is because at the start of a `p` column there is an `\everypar` setting that adds a `\strut` (with the height but not depth of a normal tabular strut)  so this works well if the paragraph is started via normal paragraph material such as your `a` but less will if you use a tex primitive box such as `\rlap` which does not start a paragraph.

Comment: Very interesting :) That's why using `\leavevmode` makes it work with `\nobreak`. One last quick question: when I need to prevent line break I should always use `\nolinebreak` instead of plain `\nobreak`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik any non expandable command (even `\relax` which does nothing) will trigger the insertion of the column template so put a p column in v mode. so `\leavevmode` is seen,  it triggers the insertion so puts tex in vmode, then it is seen again after the template has been inserted and so leaves v mode.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `\nobreak` is OK if you know which mode you are in, it acts as \linebreak` or `\pagebreak` depending, but at the start of  a table cell knowing which mode you are in  is a black art:-)